# file_get_contents false when url have spaces (encode everything not working)

Tags: php, file-get-contents, urlencode

So, the problem is in this line

```
$imageString = file_get_contents($image_url);
```

with urls that have space character it doesn't work. But if I make

```
$imageString = file_get_contents(urlencode($image_url));
```

Nothing works.I keep receiving false in the variable.

the ulr is of the kind:

```
https://s3-eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/images/12/Screenshot from 2016-04-28 18 15:54:20.png
```

Comment: Never ever use spaces in filenames in the first place!!! Only `Windows` does this sometimes  by default.

Comment: So it works when the image filenames don't have spaces?

Comment: Yes, it does. And when I encode, everything returns false.

Answer (score 1):

i'v faced the same problem and if you search about it you will see all the people tell you to use **urlencode()**, but No!! **urlencode()** wont work in this situation...

i used the **@Akram Wahid** answer and that work perfectly so i recommend it to use for file_get_contents().

and if you wonder what **escapefile_url()** does in **@Akram Wahid** answer here little explain for it:

Simply he take the url apart as array and then he use **rawurlencode()** to encode all parts that contain special characters without the main domain like (http://example.com).

so what the deference?!! here example uses  **urlencode()** and **escapefile_url()** to clarify this

```
echo escapefile_url("http://example.com/foo/bar bof/some file.jpg") . "<br>";
// http://example.com/foo/bar%20bof/some%20file.jpg

echo urlencode("http://example.com/foo/bar bof/some file.jpg") . "<br>";
// http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Ffoo%2Fbar+bof%2Fsome+file.jpg
```